# Win Server GPO Mapped Drive Missing "Connect As" functionality

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, mappeddrive

We're having an issue trying to create a policy for mapping drives. We're unable to specify a "connect as" username and password.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Microsoft removed the functionality to allow you to store credentials in GPOs because it's insecure... Yup:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2962486

So you need to write a script, or connect as the logged in user I believe.

Comment: Would you be able to suggest how to run a script like this? We're connecting between two domains in separate forests that can't see each other and so can't connect as the logged in user

Comment: @Smock ~ Granted it's been a while, but were you able to solve this? I was able to do so by storing the credentials in the logged in user's profile. Could that work for you?